# pandas.grouper.ngroup() does not perform as expected

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

I have a dataset where I would like to give each row a period index based on which time interval it are in. I am using pandas.grouper to group by every 10 minutes time interval and then using .ngroup() to create the index.

I am trying to do it for 3 datetime columns that has 0,10 and 20 minute difference -> so I want 3 different periods for each row (see example), however when using the function it groups them in the same period even though the timestamp is different. And I cannot figure out why.
In the end I want a data frame that is pr flightName with 3 different periods and with the number of times the flightName is in df (As that is the number of baggage)(as the time is the same pr flight name)

I have the following code:

```
    df_conflict['sta+time_to_infeed_left']  = df_conflict['sta'] + pd.to_timedelta(df_conflict['Time_to_infeed_left'], unit='m') 
    df_conflict['sta+time_to_infeed_left_10']  = df_conflict['sta'] + pd.to_timedelta(df_conflict['Time_to_infeed_left'], unit='m') + timedelta(minutes=10)
    df_conflict['sta+time_to_infeed_left_20']  = df_conflict['sta'] + pd.to_timedelta(df_conflict['Time_to_infeed_left'], unit='m') + timedelta(minutes=20)


    df_conflict = df_conflict.sort_values('sta')
    max_time_gap =  '10min' # time interval

    # LEFT 
    df_conflict['_temp'] = df_conflict.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='sta+time_to_infeed_left', freq=max_time_gap, origin='start')).ngroup()
    u = df_conflict['_temp'] 
    df_conflict['10min_period_left'] = np.char.add('period_', (pd.factorize(u)[0] + 1).astype(str))
    df_left = df_conflict.groupby(['10min_period_left','idx'])['idx'].count()

    # LEFT + 10
    df_conflict['_temp_10l'] = df_conflict.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='sta+time_to_infeed_left_10', freq=max_time_gap, origin='start')).ngroup()
    u1 = df_conflict['_temp_10l'] 
    df_conflict['10min_period_left_10'] = np.char.add('period_', (pd.factorize(u1)[0] + 1).astype(str))
    df_left_10 = df_conflict.groupby(['10min_period_left_10','idx'])['idx'].count()

    # LEFT + 20
    df_conflict['_temp_20l'] = df_conflict.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='sta+time_to_infeed_left_20', freq=max_time_gap, origin='start')).ngroup()
    u2 = df_conflict['_temp_20l'] 
    df_conflict['10min_period_left_20'] = np.char.add('period_', (pd.factorize(u2)[0] + 1).astype(str))
    df_left_20 = df_conflict.groupby(['10min_period_left_20','idx'])['idx'].count()
```

As can can see they are in the same period. And I don't understand why. Do you guys have any idea?
My expectation were that eg first row had period 1, 2, 3.

I have tried adding an offset, but it does not seem to change.  I hope you can help!!
[image: Output]

Test data:

```
    ArrivalFlightName   sta+time_to_infeed_left sta+time_to_infeed_left_10  sta+time_to_infeed_left_20  10min_period_left   10min_period_left_10    10min_period_left_20
2461    Flightname602   2019-12-09 07:10:35.423716620   2019-12-09 07:20:35.423716620   2019-12-09 07:30:35.423716620   period_1    period_1    period_1
229 Flightname437   2019-12-09 12:46:29.855281140   2019-12-09 12:56:29.855281140   2019-12-09 13:06:29.855281140   period_2    period_2    period_2
2044    Flightname573   2019-12-09 15:25:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:35:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:45:45.791633640   period_3    period_3    period_3
2037    Flightname573   2019-12-09 15:25:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:35:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:45:45.791633640   period_3    period_3    period_3
2036    Flightname573   2019-12-09 15:25:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:35:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:45:45.791633640   period_3    period_3    period_3
2045    Flightname573   2019-12-09 15:25:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:35:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:45:45.791633640   period_3    period_3    period_3
2040    Flightname573   2019-12-09 15:25:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:35:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:45:45.791633640   period_3    period_3    period_3
2047    Flightname573   2019-12-09 15:25:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:35:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:45:45.791633640   period_3    period_3    period_3
2039    Flightname573   2019-12-09 15:25:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:35:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:45:45.791633640   period_3    period_3    period_3
2041    Flightname573   2019-12-09 15:25:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:35:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:45:45.791633640   period_3    period_3    period_3
2042    Flightname573   2019-12-09 15:25:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:35:45.791633640   2019-12-09 15:45:45.791633640   period_3    period_3    period_3
```

Expected output (where periods of course fits to the timeintervals)

```
ArrivalFlightName Period1 period_10 period_20 No_baggage
Flightname602 1 2 3 4
Flightname437 2 3 4 1
Flightname573 17 18 19 9
```

Comment: please provide a **minimal reproducible** example (both words in bold are important)

Comment: Like this (added just now). Not sure how to add an excel file :-)